# Не виден hosts в windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, localhost

оброго времени суток!

У меня небольшая проблема.
Поставил на комп коллеги локальный сервер (easyPHP) на windows 7.
Попробовал написать в строке браузера 127.0.0.1 - открывает настройку сервера, т.е. все в порядке.

Прописал в hosts

```
127.0.0.1 tempa
127.0.0.1 tempb
```

где tempa и tempb у меня другие (здесь просто сократил).

Пишу в адресной строке браузера tempa и меня перебрасывает на поиск гугла.
Делал тоже самое на своем компе - все прекрасно.
Коллега сказал, что у него на компе вроде "доменная структура".

Если я правильно понимаю - браузер не видит hosts. Как проверить это? Может быть дело в "фишке" windows 7 (запуск от имени администратора)? Может у текущего пользователя недостаточно прав для чтения hosts? Как это поправить в винде?
Нагуглил, что эта проблема может быть из-за прокси-сервера. Если да - то как это проверить?

Это наблюдается и в IE, и в Chrome, и в Firefox.

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

[SOLVED]
Проблема решилась запуском EasyPHP от имени администратора.

Comment: Перезагружать компьютер пробовали, для вступления изменений в силу

Comment: @Данилов Виктор, вы шутите? Вы хотите перезагрузите комп после того, как зменеили hosts? Абсолютно неверно! Перезагружать надо Сервер, а не компютер.

Comment: Конечно, же комп не нужно перезагружать. Но и он, и сервер после этого рестартились кучу раз.

Comment: А вы пробовали выключить и включить?

Comment: Что выключить и включить?

Answer (score 0):

Заходим в директорию с установленной программой и находим там папочку **www**. Заходим в эту папочку и создаем в ней папку **tempa** или **tempb** и в этой папке файлик index.php и пишим в нем

```
<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>
```

Дальше в браузере вводим в адресную строку `http://127.0.0.1:8080/tempa/` и радуемся!

З.Ы. `hosts` тут не причем!

Comment: Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы на поиск не перебрасывало нужно явно указать протокол http://mysite/ и все будет ок